# spring 4.2.1 mvc resources not loading the files

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, resources

I am using Spring mvc 4.2.1 my web.xml config is as follows :

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>cureyo</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/cureyo-servlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cureyo-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cureyo-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my servlet-config.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:tx="htp://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context- 
            3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="cureyo" />

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"
    />
    <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"/>
       <property name="validator" ref="validator" /> 
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="prefix">
           <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
       </property>
       <property name="suffix">
           <value>.jsp</value>
       </property>cache-period="31556926"
   </bean>

   <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
       <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
       <property name="definitions">
           <list>
               <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/tile-defs/tiles-definition.xml</value>
           </list>
       </property>
   </bean>

   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
   <import resource="classpath:spring/db.xml" />

   </beans>
```

However, I am not able to access the resource. I get **400 error**. I have my resource at *webapplication/src/main/resource* path.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getHeader(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
>         at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.checkNotModified(ServletWebRequest.java:187)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:240)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

What is going wrong?

Comment: " I have my resource at webapplication/src/main/resource path." should resources not be placed within /webapp/resources  i.e. not within /src/main folder ?

Comment: yep i have placed in /webapp/resources  and checked it out. still it isnt working. I dont know what i am getting that exception which i have mentioned above.

Comment: as you're probable aware there have been issues related to this stacktrace output with using webapp version 2.5 but as you use 3.0 this should not apply. more likely its a dependency issue, can you add your pom.xml or list of added jars if not using Maven ?